# bash: get directory from certain part of path onwards

Tags: bash

I have an arbitrary path which contains the directory `mydir`:

```
/some/path/to/mydir/further/path/file.ext
```

I want to get the part after `mydir`, in this example:

```
/further/path/file.ext
```

Please note that the levels of subdirectories are also arbitrary, so a path like

```
/yet/another/long/path/to/mydir/file.ext
```

is also possible (where the result would be "file.ext")

The first occurrence of `mydir` should be used, so the path

```
/path/mydir/some/other/path/mydir/path/file.ext
```

should result in

```
/some/other/path/mydir/path/file.ext
```

How can one do this with bash?

**Note.** It is assumed that `mydir` will always appear enclosed between slashes.

Comment: Your question is incomplete. What do you want for `mydir/file.ext`, `/a/mydir`, `/a/mydir/`, `/mydir`, `mydir/`, `/mydir/`, etc.

Comment: I can be assumed that mydir is between slashes, so the answer is respectively: NULL, NULL, "", NULL, NULL, ""

Comment: I've edited your post to reflect this. Please review it and undo the changes if I didn't edit properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
after=${mydir#*/mydir/}
if [ "$mydir" = "$after" ]; then
  fail_with_error "Path does not contain /mydir/"
fi
after="/$after"
```

In line 1, the `#` means *substring after*, and the `*` is the usual placeholder. To be safe against directories like `.../mydirectaccess/...` I included the slashes at both ends of `mydir`. Line 5 just prepends the slash that had been taken off by line 1.

Answer (score 2):

Using [Shell Parameter Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

```
$ mydir="/some/path/to/mydir/further/path/file.ext"
$ echo ${mydir#*mydir}
/further/path/file.ext
$ mydir="/path/mydir/some/other/path/mydir/path/file.ext"
$ echo ${mydir#*mydir}
/some/other/path/mydir/path/file.ext
```

Comment: `${mydir#*/mydir/}/` would be better.

Comment: @Mat Thanks.  I prefer the official references, if available.

Answer (score 0):

Go through sed. Example:

```
echo /some/path/to/mydir/further/path/file.ext | sed 's/.*mydir/mydir/'
```

Comment: This doesn't work because of greedy match. Moreover with `mydir/amydir/` it will not work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Using bash, you can do something like this:

```
V=/yet/another/long/path/to/mydir/file.ext
R=${V#*mydir/}
echo $R
file.ext
```